# Access Violation exception when calling Com Component from IIS service

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, com

I am getting the following exception when i am trying to call a COM Component through a service deployed on IIS server.

Unhandled exception at 0x755BCB49 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Everything works fine when i run it on my local machine. It also works fine when i run the code locally on the server. The error comes when i deploy it on IIS and run from there.

I gave all the permission to the App Pool on the service folder but still isue persists.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you got any solution? i am also facing same issue